# How to insert a Rsponsive form inside slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, slider

Hy guyz!

I am using ninja-slider for responsiveness purpose. Now i have a bootstrap form that i want to display inside slider and this form should be responsive as slider moves on different resolutions screens.

I googled it to take idea but didn't found any ideal solution for this.

Help me guyz!

html

```
    <!--start-->
    <div id="ninja-slider">
        <div class="slider-inner">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a class="ns-img" href="img/002.jpg"></a>
                    <div class="caption">RESPONSIVE</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="ns-img" href="img/003.jpg"></a>
                    <div class="caption">TOUCH·ENABLED</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="ns-img" href="img/004.jpg"></a>
                    <div class="caption">VIDEO·AUDIO</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="ns-img" href="img/005.jpg"></a>
                    <div class="caption">NON·JQUERY</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="ns-img" href="img/zess.jpg"></a>
                    <div class="caption">MOBILE·FRIENDLY</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="navsWrapper">
                <div id="ninja-slider-prev"></div>
                <div id="ninja-slider-next"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--end-->

      <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Hey mate can you place make a fiddle or plnkr.

Comment: @GandalftheWhite
I can show you a screenshot. It will be perfect ! ?

Comment: I can tell you this Syed, the bootstrap's responsiveness come into effect due to its grid system, I think you'll have to make use of that.

Comment: I already have bootstrap libraries in my code. My slider is also responsive. My problem is, my form is displaying below the slider. i just want to display it inside slider. 
Hope you understand, what i exactly want to achieve !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can place the form inside slider it behaves responsive but in mobile resolution you need to to give min-height to slider. so that form won't get hidden. 
check my code at [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/XKOjoY?editors=1100)

```
li.dummySlide {
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.formSection {
  position:absolute;
  max-width:300px;  
  margin:auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;


}
```

Enjoy.. :)